# $(X,Y)$ is evenly distributed in a triangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$ $(0,3)$ $(1,3)$. Find $E(Y)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

$(X,Y)$ is evenly distributed in a triangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$ $(0,3)$ $(1,3)$.

**Calculate:**

$E(Y)$

$E(X/Y=0.4)$

$P(Y>2)$

**MY APPROACH:**

I know that first I have to find the PDF of $X$ & $Y$ and from there I can work towards marginal pdf's and then towards $E(Y)$.

The only issue is I am confused by the word **evenly distribtued** because it doesn't imply anything about the nature of R.Vs $X$ and $Y$. I know that they are continuous but which continuous R.Vs I can't figure out.

In the last how do I find the PDF just from the vertices of triangle once I have known which type of R.Vs $X$ $Y$ are?

anyone kindly guide me.

Comment: The variable "X,Y" have a joint density with support on the triangle and constant there. So you have the joint density, and therefore info about the correlation between the two variables...

Comment: I didn't get it. A bit elaboration will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The area of the triangle is $3/2$. As $(X, Y)$ is evenly distributed in this region, $f(x, y) = 2/3$

Comment: And the last question $P(Y > 2)$ can be rephrased using geometric probability: draw the triangle and then the part above $y = 2$...

Comment: That means that $E(Y)$ is not actually the centroid of the triangle, although it might look like it.